# Consulta SQL retornando valor nulo

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Simulação do BD no SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f62be/1

JavaScript:

```
// Auto-salvar
    $(function () {
        $.post("actions/autosalvar.php", function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            $("#cliente").val(data.cliente);
        }, "json");

        setInterval(function () {           
            var dados = $('#meu_form').serialize();
            $http({
              method  : 'POST',
              url     : 'actions/autosalvar.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              data : {dados: dados },
              headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
             })
        }, 2000);
    }); // Fim Auto-salvar
```

autosalvar.php

```
// Pegar os dados postados no formulário
    $dados = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
    $p = $dados['dados']; // pega o serializado do AJAX
    parse_str($p, $dados['dados']); // transforma em array de PHP
```

Formulário:

```
<form id="meu_form">
    <input type="text" name="cliente" id="cliente" style="margin-left: 10px; width:820px;"/>
</form>
```

Ao realizar um `foreach` em `$resultado`:

```
foreach($resultado as $res){
    $cliente = $res['cliente'];
    echo $cliente;
    if($cliente == NULL){echo "Campo cliente está NULL!\n";}
    //echo json_encode(array('cliente' => $cliente));
}
```

O retorno [PROBLEMA]:

```
Campo cliente está NULL!
{"cliente":null,"transportadora":null}
```

**Edição:** autosalvar.php

```
$query = $conecta->prepare("SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE id=:id_nfe");
$query->bindValue(':id_nfe',$nNFe,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de fazer seria assim:

```
$sth = $conecta->prepare('SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE id = ?');
$sth->execute(array($nNFe));
$rs = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($rs);
```

Comment: Você foi citado aqui: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5719/132 - Convido-lhe a se manifestar.

Comment: @VictorStafusa, me manifestei lá através de um comentário. Obrigado pelo aviso.

Answer (score 0):

Você já deu uma verificada no resultado que você está obtendo na linha citada abaixo?

```
$resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Utilize um var_dump na variável citada para verificar os valores e ver se realmente o resultado que você quer, está em $resultado[n]['cliente'];

```
var_dump($resultado);
```

Outra dúvida. Quando você executa a seguinte sentença SQL abaixo, substituindo os parâmetros por valores reais, você obtem os resultados esperados?

```
"SELECT * FROM nfe WHERE id=:id_nfe AND id_emitente=:id_emt AND situacao='edicao' AND (retorno_sefaz != 'autorizada' OR retorno_sefaz IS NULL)"
```

Faça as seguintes verificações para ter certeza que os valores estão sendo carregados corretamente.

Comment: Igor, já realizei `print_r` na variável `$resultado`, o campo realmente fica em branco: `[cliente] =>`

Comment: Quando substituo os valores da `ID` e `nNFe` por constantes, ainda sim é retornado nulo.

Comment: E executando a query direto no banco com os respectivos valores sendo constantes, está tento retorno? Verifique também o que você está recebendo via POST, pois é o METHOD que você está usando. Utilize um print_r($_POST); ou var_dump($_POST);

Comment: Igor, aceita o chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52382/consulta-sql-retornando-valor-nulo